# Smoothing or smoothening (smooth/smoothen)

Tags: difference

I just want to make it clear to me if there is a difference between 'smoothing' and 'smoothening' or if one of them is incorrect. 'Smoothing' is used far more often according to Google search, but occasionally I see the other version too. I found identical definitions for them both but they seem to derive from different verbs. I suppose the actual question is, what is the difference between 'smooth' and 'smoothen', but I am looking for a noun to use when talking of the act of making something smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make things *smooth* - you *smoothe* or *smoothen* them (and while these were appearing in different proportions in the past, they have nearly evened out [nowadays](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smoothen%2C%20smoothe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmoothen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmoothe%3B%2Cc0)).

The activity though is called *smoothing (a surface)* or *smoothing out (faults, creases, folds, whatever disturbs the surface)*.

[*smoothening*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smoothening%2Csmoothing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmoothening%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmoothing%3B%2Cc0) is definitely not a term in common use.

Comment: Smoothening is mainly a mathematical term nowadays.